# Using JSTL, how to read elements of set so they are sorted by their "date"(java.util.Date) property?

Tags: java, jsp, sorting, jpa, jstl

Using JPA, MVC-JSP+Servlets, JSTL

Entities and significant properties:

```
@Entity
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "post_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    @OneToMany(cascade = { ALL }, fetch = EAGER, mappedBy = "post")
    private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
    //...
}

@Entity
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "comment_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "comment_date", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private Date date;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn (name = "post_id", referencedColumnName="post_id", nullable = false)
    private Post post;
    //...
}
```

Now, in servlet's `doGet` method I have following code excerpt:

```
Post post = null;
int postId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("postId"));
post = postDao.findById(postId);

request.setAttribute("post", post);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("post.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

And in `JSP` page:

```
<c:if test="${fn:length(post.comments)>0}">
        <section id="postComments">
            <strong>Comments:</strong>

            <c:forEach items="${post.comments}" var="comment">
                <div class="postComment">
                    <div class="commentInfo"><strong>${comment.user.name}</strong> says:</div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="commentTitle">${comment.title}</div>
                    <hr>
                    <div>${comment.content}</div>
                </div>
            </c:forEach>    
        </section>
    </c:if>
```

This way I AM getting all comments of the post, but I would like to have them sorted by their `date` attribute. I know that `Set` is not ordered collection, so how can I read these comments to have them sorted by their `date` property?

Comment: Use `TreeSet` instead of `HashSet`. And pass a `Comparator` to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate the JPA relationship with `@OrderBy` which will retrieve the entities from the database in the specified order using the provided field.  Also change the set implementation to `LinkedHashSet` to retain order from the database.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = { ALL }, fetch = EAGER, mappedBy = "post")
@OrderBy("date DESC")
private Set<Comment> comments = new LinkedHashSet<Comment>();
```

For more information you could watch this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sx76pO00S8s) I created that explains how to use `@OrderBy`.

Comment: Thanks A LOT. So simpler than to sort elements explicitly. Straight to the point.

Comment: @Wlad Glad I could help!  Agreed, and I believe the database will perform the sort faster than the application layer.

Comment: Great, thanks! If you (say) dont have access to modify the `@Entity` class, is there an easy way to do this in the presentation layer?